# Limit Total Selections in Listboxfor in MVC4

Tags: c#, javascript, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm setting up a front end that uses MVC4.  There's several Listboxfor boxes but I want to limit the number of each box up to a certain amount.  For instance Listboxfor1 should have a max of 5 selectable items whereas Listboxfor2 should have a max of 7.

I've done several searches around the web and only found a server side fix using webforms and javascript.  While that's all peaches and cream I can't seem to figure out how apply it to MVC.

Below is a snippet of what my listboxfor code looks like

```
@Html.ListBoxFor(model => model.Games,
   new SelectList(Model.Games.Where(m => m.action == action), "GameID", "Title"),
   new { id="listbox" + action, @class="lbGames"})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cant fix this problem using just using Html helpers. You can make some workaround using javascript.
This `@Html.ListBoxFor` will be converted into html and will look like:

```
   <select id="listbox" class="lbGames">
      <option value="Action1">Action1</option>
      <option value="Action2">Action2</option>
      ...
   </select>
```

so you can write something like this using jquery:

```
$("#listbox").change(function() {
  var mySelectedOptions = $.find('#listbox option:selected');
  if(if(mySelectedOptions).length > 5){
     // Your code here, if selected amount exceeds 5
     alert('hey bro you selected more than 5 elements!!!');
  }
});
```

**Notice, i didn't tested this code. This is just a fast example, to help you to find right way.**

Comment: Thank you.  I was hoping this wouldn't be the only option but it'll work just as well.  I would give you a useful check but I can't yet! Thank you very much @Maris.